# Не выполняется запрос для MySQL

Tags: pdo, база-данных, php, sql, mysql

Делаю запрос на добавление элемента на **PHP через PDO к базе данных MySQL**. Когда пишу запрос за пределами функции всё нормально работает. Как только оборачиваю запрос в функцию, то он перестаёт работать, притом без сообщений об ошибки, элемент просто не добавляется в Б.Д. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём может быть проблема?
код:

```
 <?
//файл с данными для подключения к БД.
include "config.php";

// функция выполняет простой запрос
function test1(){
        $DB_DSN="mysql:host=".$CONFIG[db_host].";dbname=".$CONFIG[db_database].";charset=utf8";
        $conn = new PDO( $DB_DSN, $CONFIG[db_user],$CONFIG[db_password], array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'") );

        //выполняем запрос
        $st = $conn->prepare( "INSERT INTO user1 ( email, pass, prava) VALUES ( 'wwfdsdf24', 'fsdf24',7)");
        $st->execute();
        return 0;
}   
//выполняем запрос данный запрос нормально отработает
$DB_DSN="mysql:host=".$CONFIG[db_host].";dbname=".$CONFIG[db_database].";charset=utf8";
$conn = new PDO( $DB_DSN, $CONFIG[db_user],$CONFIG[db_password], array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'") );

$st = $conn->prepare( "INSERT INTO user1 ( email, pass, prava) VALUES ( 'wwfdsdf2', 'fsdf2',8)");
$st->execute();

//выполняем запрос через функцию, почему-то новый элемент уже не будет добавлен. Что это за магия?
test1();
?>
```

Comment: зачем return 0; ?

Comment: Да я уже как только не пробовал, без него точно так же не работает. Просто уже на всякий случай написал.

Comment: Просто убивает уже.... Пишу запрос в функции - он не работает. Пишу ровно тоже самое, но вне функции - оно работает. Как это вообще возможно?

Comment: var_dump() юзали?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Внутри функции test() переменные для подключения к базе являются локальными. Их нужно передать или как параметры, или обозначить как global.

http://php.net/manual/ru/language.variables.scope.php 
вот статья по теме, там пример с переменной $a - точь в точь ваша ситуация, только в простейшем виде.

Comment: global - есть ЗЛО, параметрами передавай и все

Comment: по хорошему нужно сделать обертку для конфига базы данных и просто объект передавать